# Looping through array one at a time with onClick React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create a button that loops through a specific set of themes when pressed. Also, after displaying the last theme, it would loop back to the beginning of the array. I created a handle function that would loop through the various themes by updating the custom react hooks function useThemes. However, my attempt is not producing any results. Here is my code, thank you for any help.

```
 const { theme, setTheme } = useTheme();

 const themes = [
  { name: "Normal" },
  { name: "Dark" },
  { name: "Forrest" },
  { name: "Pink" },
  { name: "Sky" },
  { name: "Strawberry" },
 ];

 let myIndex = 1;

 const handleColorChange = (e: any) => {
  setTheme(e.themes.name[myIndex].toLowerCase());
  myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % themes.length;
 };

       <button onClick={handleColorChange}>
          
        </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the handlerColorChange method, you are trying to get a property that doesn't exist in the `e` variable, I think you meant to get it from the themes array instead.

Try this:

```
const handleColorChange = (e: any) => {
  setTheme(themes[myIndex].name.toLowerCase());
  myIndex = (myIndex + 1) % themes.length;
 };
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. This function does not produce any errors however, its not looping through all of the array. Should I not use the modulo operator?

Comment: Tested the function and it worked as expected, it changes the theme for every click of the button

Answer (score 0):

Just store the theme index in state. Local variables in a component are not persisted across renders.

For example:

```js
const [themeIdx, setThemeIdx] = useState(0);
// or change this in your useTheme hook

const handleColorChange = (e: any) => {
    setThemeIdx((themeIdx + 1) % themes.length);
};
const theme = themes[themeIdx];
```